# Put label in the "center" of an SVG path

Tags: path, svg, raphael, polygon

I'm trying to draw a label on a polygon of an svg file. The problem I'm facing is to find out roughly the center of this polygon to place the label, as the path's coordinates are in svg format and need to be parsed. Is there an easier way to determine the center of an svg polygon (maybe someone can point out a javascript library or a snippet)? I'm using Raphael javascript library to manipulate the svg, but it doesn't seem to go beyond the standard svg functionality.

Answer (score 13):

You could try the following approximation for doing something similar to the polygon suggestion, based on SVG DOM methods:

```
var totalPathLength = pathelm.getTotalLength();
var step = totalPathLength / 100;
for(var dist=0; dist < totalPathLength; dist+=step)
{
  var pt = pathelm.getPointAtLength(dist);
  addToAverage(pt.x, pt.y);
}
```

I think the simplest approach is to use the center of the path element's boundingbox (pathelm.getBBox()), that's simpler than the polygon suggestion.

Comment: PS: `var bbox = p.getBBox(); var x = Math.floor(bbox.x + bbox.width/2.0); var y = Math.floor(bbox.y + bbox.height/2.0);` did the trick for me, thx.

Comment: Thanks @Iwe! That was much simpler that I could imagine :)

Comment: @Iwe's comment deserves to be a separate answer. It's a simpler, different approach with different pros and cons. Here's a [**JSBIN demo of both using Vietnam and Canada country shapes**](http://jsbin.com/orAzoFI/3/edit) showing some key points and differences: that neither method guarentees the centre will be inside the shape, and that Erik's method pulls the centre towards parts of the path that are more fractured/complex/have a higher relative circumference.

Comment: @user568458 read the last sentence of my answer, I did suggest the getBBox method, though I did leave out how to compute the center of the bbox rectangle because I thought it was so trivial. It's true that none of the methods guarantee the computed center is inside the shape.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you could try doing is to calculate the center by taking the average of all the points in the polygon. It should work for all but the most irregular of polygons. I've used the same algorithm to good effect in my programs.

Best of luck.

Comment: Sorry, for not clearly phrasing my question. The problem is more about how to get the coordinates from the path's d-attribute which is in this format
<path d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z" fill="red" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" /> in order to calculate the center or to find a javascript library that does that without me parsing the attribute according to the svg spec.

Comment: The first problem to solve first is to convert the svg into polygon first. I have been searching for a code to convert the svg paths into polygons but couldn't find one. Maybe have to dig-up on the source codes of svg projects

Answer (score -3):

Insert a text tag inside the svg and position it by calculating the width and hight

```
 <svg width="447pt" height="559pt" viewBox="0 0 894 1118" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    ............
    ............

   <text x="450" y="300" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15" fill="red" >
        Text To Show
   </text>
</svg>
```