# How to center text inside path?

Tags: angular, svg, text, path, frontend

I have array of paths( which I get from backend server, with paths I will build custom floor plan) and      to this paths I have to give some names which have to be visible and editable(exactly have to be located in center of each path)

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 2000 1024" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="2000" height="1024" fill="white"/>
  <rect x="930.5" y="0.5" width="139" height="570" fill="#D5D5D5" stroke="black"/>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let path of paths">
    <path [attr.d]="path.d" [attr.stroke]="path.stroke"  data-boutiqueId="path.boutiqueId"></path>

    <text style="font-size: 24px;">
      <textPath [attr.href]="'#' + path.boutique.id" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">
        {{ path.boutique.id }}
      </textPath>
    </text>
  </ng-container>

  <rect x="1.5" y="1.5" width="1997" height="1021" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip0_103_2">
      <rect width="2000" height="1024" fill="white"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

That is my current code, but it

```
 <textPath [attr.href]="'#' + path.boutique.id" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">
        {{ path.boutique.id }}
      </textPath>
```

does not displayed, how I can fix that?

Comment: textPath will draw the text along the path, it won't draw it in the centre of a path.

Comment: A Native JS solution processing all ``<path>`` and adding a label is at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76293125/how-can-i-put-a-text-inside-and-centered-of-that-svg-path/76296374#76296374

Answer (score 0):

```
<textPath [attr.href]=`'#' + ${path.boutique.id}` startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">
  {{ path.boutique.id }}
</textPath>
```

try this if works