How can I hover over text and change the hover state of an SVG
Is it possible to hover over the text and have the state color change as if it was also hovered?


#us-map {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

path:hover,
circle:hover {
  stroke: #ffffff !important;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  fill: #D3D3D3 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mp-label-out {
  fill: #4bb95a;
}
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="us-map" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" sodipodi:docname="NEVI.svg" inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" x="0px"
  y="0px" width="959px" height="593px" viewBox="174 100 959 593" enable-background="new 174 100 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
        <sodipodi:namedview bordercolor="#666666" objecttolerance="10" pagecolor="#ffffff" borderopacity="1" gridtolerance="10" guidetolerance="10" inkscape:cx="509.19152" inkscape:cy="282.2353" inkscape:zoom="1.2137643" showgrid="false" id="namedview71" inkscape:current-layer="g5" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:window-y="-8" inkscape:window-x="-8" inkscape:pageopacity="0" inkscape:window-height="1017" inkscape:window-width="1920" inkscape:pageshadow="2">
            </sodipodi:namedview>
        <g id="g5">
            <path data-state="HI" fill="#4bb95a" d="M407.1,619.3l1.9-3.6l2.3-0.3l0.3,0.8l-2.1,3.1H407.1z M417.3,615.6l6.1,2.6l2.1-0.3l1.6-3.9   l-0.6-3.4l-4.2-0.5l-4,1.8L417.3,615.6z M448,625.6l3.7,5.5l2.4-0.3l1.1-0.5l1.5,1.3l3.7-0.2l1-1.5l-2.9-1.8l-1.9-3.7l-2.1-3.6   l-5.8,2.9L448,625.6z M468.2,634.5l1.3-1.9l4.7,1l0.6-0.5l6.1,0.6l-0.3,1.3l-2.6,1.5l-4.4-0.3L468.2,634.5z M473.5,639.7l1.9,3.9   l3.1-1.1l0.3-1.6l-1.6-2.1l-3.7-0.3V639.7z M480.5,638.5l2.3-2.9l4.7,2.4l4.4,1.1l4.4,2.7v1.9l-3.6,1.8l-4.8,1l-2.4-1.5   L480.5,638.5z M497.1,654.1l1.6-1.3l3.4,1.6l7.6,3.6l3.4,2.1l1.6,2.4l1.9,4.4l4,2.6l-0.3,1.3l-3.9,3.2l-4.2,1.5l-1.5-0.6l-3.1,1.8   l-2.4,3.2l-2.3,2.9l-1.8-0.2l-3.6-2.6l-0.3-4.5l0.6-2.4l-1.6-5.7l-2.1-1.8l-0.2-2.6l2.3-1l2.1-3.1l0.5-1l-1.6-1.8L497.1,654.1z"/>
        </g>
        <g><text data-state="HI" class="mp-label-out" font-size="12" y="350" x="-80" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 517 302)" cursor="pointer">HI</text></g>
</svg>




Doesn't hurt to learn some extra JS/SVG coding; take inspiration from this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76293125/how-can-i-put-a-text-inside-and-centered-of-that-svg-path/76296374#76296374

You can use the :has selector instead.
#us-map:has(path:hover, circle:hover, text:hover) {
    circle,
    path {
      stroke: #ffffff !important;
      stroke-width: 2px;
      stroke-linejoin: round;
      fill: #D3D3D3 !important;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
}



#us-map {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#us-map:has(path:hover, circle:hover, text:hover) {
  circle,
  path {
    stroke: #ffffff !important;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke-linejoin: round;
    fill: #D3D3D3 !important;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.mp-label-out {
  fill: #4bb95a;
}
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="us-map" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" sodipodi:docname="NEVI.svg" inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" x="0px"
  y="0px" width="959px" height="593px" viewBox="174 100 959 593" enable-background="new 174 100 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
        <sodipodi:namedview bordercolor="#666666" objecttolerance="10" pagecolor="#ffffff" borderopacity="1" gridtolerance="10" guidetolerance="10" inkscape:cx="509.19152" inkscape:cy="282.2353" inkscape:zoom="1.2137643" showgrid="false" id="namedview71" inkscape:current-layer="g5" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:window-y="-8" inkscape:window-x="-8" inkscape:pageopacity="0" inkscape:window-height="1017" inkscape:window-width="1920" inkscape:pageshadow="2">
            </sodipodi:namedview>
        <g id="g5">
            <path data-state="HI" fill="#4bb95a" d="M407.1,619.3l1.9-3.6l2.3-0.3l0.3,0.8l-2.1,3.1H407.1z M417.3,615.6l6.1,2.6l2.1-0.3l1.6-3.9   l-0.6-3.4l-4.2-0.5l-4,1.8L417.3,615.6z M448,625.6l3.7,5.5l2.4-0.3l1.1-0.5l1.5,1.3l3.7-0.2l1-1.5l-2.9-1.8l-1.9-3.7l-2.1-3.6   l-5.8,2.9L448,625.6z M468.2,634.5l1.3-1.9l4.7,1l0.6-0.5l6.1,0.6l-0.3,1.3l-2.6,1.5l-4.4-0.3L468.2,634.5z M473.5,639.7l1.9,3.9   l3.1-1.1l0.3-1.6l-1.6-2.1l-3.7-0.3V639.7z M480.5,638.5l2.3-2.9l4.7,2.4l4.4,1.1l4.4,2.7v1.9l-3.6,1.8l-4.8,1l-2.4-1.5   L480.5,638.5z M497.1,654.1l1.6-1.3l3.4,1.6l7.6,3.6l3.4,2.1l1.6,2.4l1.9,4.4l4,2.6l-0.3,1.3l-3.9,3.2l-4.2,1.5l-1.5-0.6l-3.1,1.8   l-2.4,3.2l-2.3,2.9l-1.8-0.2l-3.6-2.6l-0.3-4.5l0.6-2.4l-1.6-5.7l-2.1-1.8l-0.2-2.6l2.3-1l2.1-3.1l0.5-1l-1.6-1.8L497.1,654.1z"/>
        </g>
        <g><text data-state="HI" class="mp-label-out" font-size="12" y="350" x="-80" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 517 302)" cursor="pointer">HI</text></g>
</svg>




EDIT:
Pure CSS can't select the matching path based on the same data-attribute, so you'll need to depend on the DOM structure which could be fragile. You'll want some rearrangement on your SVG DOM structure as well.
However, since you've used the JQuery tag, this can be handled easily with a hover event.


$("#us-map text").hover(function() {
  const name = $(this).data('state');
  $(`#us-map path[data-state=${name}],circle[data-state=${name}]`).addClass('state-selected');
}, function() {
  const name = $(this).data('state');
  $(`#us-map path[data-state=${name}],circle[data-state=${name}]`).removeClass('state-selected');
});
#us-map {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.state-selected,
path:hover,
circle:hover {
  stroke: #ffffff !important;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  fill: #D3D3D3 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mp-label-out {
  fill: #4bb95a;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="us-map" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" sodipodi:docname="NEVI.svg" inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" x="0px"
  y="0px" width="959px" height="593px" viewBox="174 100 959 593" enable-background="new 174 100 959 593" xml:space="preserve">
        <sodipodi:namedview bordercolor="#666666" objecttolerance="10" pagecolor="#ffffff" borderopacity="1" gridtolerance="10" guidetolerance="10" inkscape:cx="509.19152" inkscape:cy="282.2353" inkscape:zoom="1.2137643" showgrid="false" id="namedview71" inkscape:current-layer="g5" inkscape:window-maximized="1" inkscape:window-y="-8" inkscape:window-x="-8" inkscape:pageopacity="0" inkscape:window-height="1017" inkscape:window-width="1920" inkscape:pageshadow="2">
            </sodipodi:namedview>
        <g id="g5">
            <path data-state="HI" fill="#4bb95a" d="M407.1,619.3l1.9-3.6l2.3-0.3l0.3,0.8l-2.1,3.1H407.1z M417.3,615.6l6.1,2.6l2.1-0.3l1.6-3.9   l-0.6-3.4l-4.2-0.5l-4,1.8L417.3,615.6z M448,625.6l3.7,5.5l2.4-0.3l1.1-0.5l1.5,1.3l3.7-0.2l1-1.5l-2.9-1.8l-1.9-3.7l-2.1-3.6   l-5.8,2.9L448,625.6z M468.2,634.5l1.3-1.9l4.7,1l0.6-0.5l6.1,0.6l-0.3,1.3l-2.6,1.5l-4.4-0.3L468.2,634.5z M473.5,639.7l1.9,3.9   l3.1-1.1l0.3-1.6l-1.6-2.1l-3.7-0.3V639.7z M480.5,638.5l2.3-2.9l4.7,2.4l4.4,1.1l4.4,2.7v1.9l-3.6,1.8l-4.8,1l-2.4-1.5   L480.5,638.5z M497.1,654.1l1.6-1.3l3.4,1.6l7.6,3.6l3.4,2.1l1.6,2.4l1.9,4.4l4,2.6l-0.3,1.3l-3.9,3.2l-4.2,1.5l-1.5-0.6l-3.1,1.8   l-2.4,3.2l-2.3,2.9l-1.8-0.2l-3.6-2.6l-0.3-4.5l0.6-2.4l-1.6-5.7l-2.1-1.8l-0.2-2.6l2.3-1l2.1-3.1l0.5-1l-1.6-1.8L497.1,654.1z"/>
        </g>
        <g><text data-state="HI" class="mp-label-out" font-size="12" y="350" x="-80" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 517 302)" cursor="pointer">HI</text></g>
</svg>




Thank you. Is it possible to target that specific text class? Hovering over the  text causes additional states to hover as well. Very much appreciate your detailed explanation.

Pure CSS can't target elements by attribute, and depending on your DOM structure requires more detail provided and could be fragile.  However, this can be done easily using JQuery/JS.

It looks like I wasn't going to get far with (text:hover > path #hawaii{fill: #D3D3D3}) Thank you very much for your solution. Absolutely amazing! May you have a wonderful day.

You are welcome! Since text is after path, only way I can think of with CSS is to select path using nth-last-child  and check that it's not subsequence (~) of text:hover, which can get pretty complicated especially they are all under different <g> tag. That's why I said you probably want to rearrange the DOM into a better structure if you want to do so.
